# tikz: using of cyrillic characters for node label

Tags: character-encoding, latex, tex, tikz

I'm trying to use Cyrillic characters for node label, but seems like they are ignored. Probably should define label format in some way but wasn't able to find any guide for this.

Here is simple example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto Light}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,
   draw=black,
   label=$label text текст надписи$]
    (c) at (0,0){Текст ноды Node text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which producing the following with xelatex:

[image: output]

so:

1. Cyrillic characters missing in label
2. white space is also missing for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Don't abuse math mode for whole words!

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto Light}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,
   draw=black,
   label={label text текст надписи}]
    (c) at (0,0){Текст ноды Node text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```